# How to install Autodesk Maya 2016 in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

Please tell me what is wrong and what went wrong. I'm trying to install Maya 2016 according to the instructions from [this site](https://gist.github.com/MRTELIMS/c7452f8106874f30117e#file-gistfile1-sh-L82).

I tried to run it through the terminal, via the menu dash, but it still does not work. It constantly complains Maya.bin

[image]

I tried running `sudo chown -hR sne_byorn/home/sne_byorn/maya` (see this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVh1U.jpg)) but it did not help. All the same, even when you run through a shortcut via dash menu, even in terminal sudo maya, maya -style gtk - it only has time to load the splash screen and everything and then nothing.

Comment: Why not ask it at github?

Comment: Because it is a service to answer the question, it is associated with Linux systems and particularly Ubuntu. I think here I will answer as many people here probably in Maya put on your computer.

Comment: Sorry for my English. I understood what you wrote. the fact is that link that I wrote, is suitable not only for Maya 2015, but for the 2016 version, it was written in the guide on the website where I found this link. And what you say about the alien I found them there in the guide a team - sudo apt-get install -y alien csh tcsh libaudiofile-dev libglw1-mesa elfutils gamin libglw1-mesa-dev mesa-utils xfstt ttf-liberation xfonts- 100dpi xfonts-75dpi ttf-mscorefonts-installer

Answer (score -4):

Have tried this enter in the terminal:

```
sudo aptitude install --reinstall libssl.so.0.9.8
```

and then this

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: sne_byorn@sne:~$ sudo aptitude libstc++.so.6
sudo: aptitude: command not found
sne_byorn@sne:~$

Comment: Sorry, after I wrote that the team aptitude terminal is not found, I went online and found how to install it, sudo apt-get install aptitude then again, I entered the command that you wrote, but the terminal wrote me the following items:
sne_byorn@sne:~$ sudo aptitude libstc++.so.6
unknown command «libstc++.so.6»
aptitude 0.6.8.2

Comment: sne_byorn @ sne: ~ $ sudo aptitude install libstc ++. so.6
Unable to find packages containing «libstc ++. So.6» in its name or description
Unable to find packages containing «libstc ++. So.6» in its name or description
No packages will be installed, removed, or upgraded.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove the packages mentioned, and 1 not upgraded.
You need to get 0 B archives. After unpacking 0 B will be occupied.
                                                 
sne_byorn @ sne: ~ $

Comment: That makes sense because libstc++.so.6 is also an rpm package. [Maya 2016 only runs as sudo? (Ubuntu 14.04)](http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/installation-licensing/maya-2016-only-runs-as-sudo-ubuntu/td-p/5670045). *It's working now! There where files inside $HOME with the root userid. I used the "chown" command to fix the userid and Maya 2016 is now running as a normal user.*

Comment: I've already read, thank you. And he did this by running sudo chown -hR sne_byorn/home/sne_byorn/maya
But it did not help. All the same, even when you run through a shortcut via dash menu, even in terminal sudo maya, maya -style gtk - she only has time to load the splash screen and everything and then nothing :(
Link to screen - http://i.imgur.com/SLbMzK7.jpg

Comment: You have to install aptitude first, and enter this sudo apt-get install aptitude

Comment: Sorry, after I wrote that the team aptitude terminal is not found, I went online and found how to install it, sudo apt-get install aptitude then again, I entered the command that you wrote, but the terminal wrote me the following items: sne_byorn@sne:~$ sudo aptitude libstc++.so.6 unknown command «libstc++.so.6» aptitude 0.6.8.2

Comment: When giving beginning users the instruction to use `aptitude`, please tell them to install it first.   Furthermore, this doesn't answer the question.  To remove the negative reputation points, [edit] your answer, improve it, and drop a note so that I can review my assessment of your answer.  Alternatively, [delete] it altogether and the negative reputation points will be reversed automatically by the system. (I do this too for answers that give me negative reputation points) **;-)**